# How to implement a (WYMEditor-based) text editor plugin for django CMS 3.0

Tags: django, content-management-system, wymeditor

django CMS before version 3 included WYMeditor and TinyMCE as options; now text editing plugins have been spun out from the core. The only one so far provided is for CKeditor.

I have begun trying to implement a WYMeditor-based text plugin for django CMS 3.0.

My work so far: https://github.com/evildmp/djangocms-text-wymeditor

I also want to document this, because other people will likely need to do the same for their preferred editor: https://github.com/divio/django-cms/pull/1883

The code I have produced so far manages to launch the WYMeditor, but the two most obvious so far are:

- nothing is saved on hitting Save
- it's looking for JS files in weird places (e.g. /static/admin/js/lang/en.js, when nothing as far as I can tell has told it to look in /static/admin)

I am wondering which of these three strategies is likely to be most successful:

- start by trying to replicate the functionality of the text plugin code from django CMS 2.x (what I have been doing so far)
- start by trying to follow the example in the djangocms-text-ckeditor plugin
- start by getting a working WYM widget for a textarea, and then trying to create a django CMS plugin based on that

Answer (score 0):

> nothing is saved on hitting Save

Do you have the class `wymupdate` on your Save button? That is required in order to automatically update your HTML based on your editing upon form submission.

> it's looking for JS files in weird places

It looks like you're setting `STATIC_URL` based on `settings.STATIC_URL`. That's likely where the `/static/admin` path is coming from.

As far as strategies, I would say your current strategy of trying to replicate the functionality from Django CMS 2.x is the way to go. I'm certainly not a Django-CMS expert, however.

Answer (score 0):

An answer to the root of your question, which I interpret as "How can I use WYMeditor with Django CMS 3", is to just use [djangocms_wymeditor_plugin](https://github.com/wymeditor/djangocms_wymeditor_plugin). This worked against the Beta version of Django CMS 3 that was available a couple months ago, so is likely to still work.